# stbir_resize_uint8 crashing on memory access

Tags: stb-image

I'm using stb_image to upload an image to the GPU. If I just upload the image with stbi_load I can confirm  (nvidia Nsight) that the image is correctly stored in the GPU memory. However, some images I like to resize before I upload the to the GPU. In this case, I get a crash. This is the code:

```
    int      textureWidth;
    int      textureHeight;
    int      textureChannelCount;
    stbi_uc* pixels = stbi_load(fullPath.string().c_str(), &textureWidth, &textureHeight, &textureChannelCount, STBI_rgb_alpha);

    if (!pixels) {
        char error[512];
        sprintf_s(error, "Failed to load image %s!", pathToTexture);
        throw std::runtime_error(error);
    }

    stbi_uc* resizedPixels = nullptr;
    uint32_t imageSize     = 0;
    if (scale > 1.0001f || scale < 0.9999f) {
        stbir_resize_uint8(pixels, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, resizedPixels, textureWidth * scale, textureHeight * scale, 0, textureChannelCount);
        stbi_image_free(pixels);
        textureWidth *= scale;
        textureHeight *= scale;
        imageSize = textureWidth * textureHeight * textureChannelCount;
    } else {
        resizedPixels = pixels;
        imageSize     = textureWidth * textureHeight * textureChannelCount;
    }

    // Upload the image to the gpu
```

When this code is run with scale set to `1.0f`, it works fine. However, when I set the scale to `0.25f`, the program crashes in method `stbir_resize_uint8`. The image I'm providing in both cases is a `1920x1080 RGBA PNG`. Alpha channel is set to `1.0f` across the whole image.

Which function do I have to use to resize the image?

EDIT: If I allocate the memory myself, the function no longer crashes and works fine. But I though stb handles all memory allocation internally. Was I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you found and solved the problem in your edit but here's some useful advice anyway:

---

It seems like the comments in the [source](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_resize.h#L38) (which is also the documentation) don't explicitly mention that you have to allocate memory for the resized image, but it becomes clear when you take a closer look at the function's signature:

```
STBIRDEF int stbir_resize_uint8(     const unsigned char *input_pixels , int input_w , int input_h , int input_stride_in_bytes,
                                           unsigned char *output_pixels, int output_w, int output_h, int output_stride_in_bytes,
                                     int num_channels);
```

Think about how you yourself would return the address of a memory chunk that you allocated in a function. The easiest would be to return the pointer directly like so:

```
unsigned char* allocate_memory( int size )
{ return (unsigned char*) malloc(size); }
```

However the return seems to be reserved for error codes, so your only option would be to manipulate the pointer as a side-effect. To do that, you'd need to pass a pointer to it (pointer to pointer):

```
int allocate_memory( unsigned char** pointer_to_array, int size )
{
    *pointer_to_array = (unsigned char*) malloc(size);
    /* Check if allocation was successful and do other stuff... */
    return 0;
}
```

If you take a closer look at the resize function's signature, you'll notice that there's no such parameter passed, so there's no way for it to return the address of internally allocated memory. (`unsigned char* output_pixels` instead of `unsigned char** output_pixels`). As a result, you have to allocate the memory for the resized image yourself.

I hope this helps you in the future.

---

There is a [mention](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/b42009b3b9d4ca35bc703f5310eedc74f584be58/stb_image_resize.h#L38) of memory allocation in the docs but as far as I understand, it's about allocations required to perform the resizing, which is unrelated to the output.